# ROS Cython: dynamic module does not define module export function (PyInit_...)

Tags: python, cython, ros, setup.py, catkin

I have made a python wrapping of a c++ class similar to [here](https://github.com/longjie/ros_cython_example) and [here](https://github.com/marcoesposito1988/cython_catkin_example). but the generated python wrapper is only usable in python2 while giving the following error in python3:

```
dynamic module does not define module export function (PyInit_...)
```

my **setup.py** looks like the following:

```
## ! DO NOT MANUALLY INVOKE THIS setup.py, USE CATKIN INSTEAD

from distutils.core import setup
from catkin_pkg.python_setup import generate_distutils_setup

setup_args = generate_distutils_setup(
    packages=['hw_interface_pkg'],
    package_dir={'': 'src'},
    requires=['std_msgs', 'rospy'],
    language_level="3",
    compiler_directives={'language_level' : "3"}
)

setup(**setup_args)
```

following [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34603628/how-to-specify-python-3-source-in-cythons-setup-py) I tried adding `language_level = "3"` or `compiler_directives={'language_level' : "3"}` to the above *setup_args* but none solved the problem.

my pyx file also looks like:

```
cdef extern from "remote_hw.h":
    cdef cppclass ROBOTHardwareInterface:
        ROBOTHardwareInterface() except +
        double c_fibonacci(double n);

cdef class PyHWInterface:
    cdef ROBOTHardwareInterface c_obj
    def __cinit__(self):
        pass
    def fibonnaci_func(self,n):
        return self.c_obj.c_fibonacci(n)
```

-------------edit

I made sure setup.py is called by python3. but still the same issue.....

Comment: That's correct. An extension module built with Python 2 will not be usable on Python 3. You need to rebuild it with Python 3 (i.e. invoke setup.py with Python 3). language_level is to do with how Cython interprets the pyx file so is not related to your problem.

Comment: @DavidW I see, the thing is setup.py is invoked automatically during a so called "catkin build" command where it is likely the "catkin_python_setup()" in the CMakeLists.txt that does it. but it's not clear to me how I can make it invoke setup.py with python3. or any other solution/hack...

Comment: @DavidW I made sure setup.py is called by python3.6 but still the same issue presists.....

Comment: What is the output file called? It should be something like `filename.cpython-36.so` (or .pyx). If it doesn't have an extension with the version in it then it probably isn't being called by Python 3.6. I've never heard of catkin before so have no useful advice on that.

Comment: @DavidW inside setup.py I had prtint(sys.version), which printed "3.6.9 (default, Apr 18 2020, 01:56:04)". there is a similar issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8024805/cython-compiled-c-extension-importerror-dynamic-module-does-not-define-init-fu although non of the ideas in it has worked for me so far

Comment: the generated .so files don't have any .cpython ending just hw_interface.so for example

Comment: But how do you call setup.py? My guess is that you still have so from python2 around.

Comment: @ead first I call "catkin build" which in a CMakeLists.txt file applies catkin_python_setup(). Then although it uses python3 to call setup.py, the above issue is there. There are some cython related cmake files which I suspect might be the place for solving the issue https://github.com/longjie/ros_cython_example/tree/master/cmake but I have no clue at all yet

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37070304/how-to-build-opencv-for-python3-when-both-python2-and-python3-are-installed? Something like this? It might be you have to specify it with cmake? That's a guess though