# 'GLIBCXX_3.4.30' not found for librosa in conda virtual environment (after trying out a lot of solutions)?

Tags: linux, anaconda, librosa

I am trying to `import librosa`, but I am thrown with this error:

```
/home/lakshya/anaconda3/envs/tff_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/zmq/backend/cython/../../../../.././libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.30' not found (required by /home/lakshya/anaconda3/envs/tff_env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scipy/fft/_pocketfft/pypocketfft.cpython-39-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
```

I tried the following to fix it based on the other similar questions that I browsed through:

1. `sudo apt-get install libstdc++6`

   It's output: **libstdc++6 is already the newest version (10.2.1-6).**
2. `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`

   It's output: **0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.**
3. `strings /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIBCXX`

   It's output: **GLIBCXX version up to GLIBCXX_3.4.28**
4. `conda install libgcc` in my virtual env "tff_env"

   It's output: **libgcc-7.2.0 installed in tff_env**
5. Pip installed the libgcc package in the virtual environment as well. Didn't work.

What can I do?

My OS: Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)

Comment: It looks like you somehow ended up with `scipy` built with a newer version of gcc than you have installed by default. Do you have  other versions of gcc installed somewhere on your system? (libgcc version is irrelevant, don't bother with it).

Comment: I just installed Debian 11 2 days back. I haven't explicitly installed any gcc separately. The one thing I did was install Python3.10 using `make altinstall` and Anaconda. Then within the conda environment "tff_env" I installed tensorflow-federated. How do I check if I have other gcc versions somewhere? Or perhaps downgrade scipy so it doesn't need the gcc version that I don't have?

Comment: I am not entirely familiar with how anaconda works, does it build binaries locally or download forom somewhere? If the latter, there is a gap, as it downloaded a version that won't run on your system. Not sure how to deal with it. I personally try to always install the latest available gcc/g++/libraries to avoid this kind of problem and to have the latest set of features. Try either installing g++12 or downgrading your packages (but you may have to downgrade a lot). Also, avoid installing from source with `make install` and the like. If you need Python10, find a package for it.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Just been tackling a similar problem, it looks like you need to ensure you have the latest version of gcc. Running:

```
conda install -c conda-forge gcc=12.1.0
```

Fixed the error for me.

Comment: worked for arch linux x86 (with nvidia gpu) in my case

Comment: Worked for me as well when required by /usr/lib/libzimg.so.2

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04 not work...

Comment: Did not work for me on Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.15.0-46-generic x86_64).

Comment: Worked for me on 22.04.1.

Comment: Working fine with Ubuntu 22.10 && conda 23.1.0. Thank you very much!

Comment: `conda install -c conda-forge gcc=12.2.0` worked for me

Comment: Worked for me on Fedora 37 Workstation.

Answer (score 31):

After my search on anaconda packages, I found only the package "libstdcxx" will substantially bring new "libstdc++.so.6" file to the conda environment (while "gcc", "gcc_linux-64", and "libgcc-ng" cannot).
Thus, installing the following package can fix this problem for me.

`conda install -c conda-forge libstdcxx-ng=12`

PS: dfcorbin's answer `conda install -c conda-forge gcc=12` not works for me.

Comment: For me as well, `gcc=12` didn't solve the problem but `libstdcxx-ng=12` did

Comment: It worked for me (U22 LTS) 

Comment: can I install both side by side?

Answer (score 15):

None of the above answers worked for me, unfortunately. What I ended up doing was to manually inspect the `libstdc++.so.6` file.

First, I checked the system file, and it returned nothing on my side:

> `strings /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIBCXX_3.4.30`

Then, I took a look the conda file, and it was there:

> `strings /path-to-your-conda/envs/your-env-name/lib/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIBCXX_3.4.30`

This indicates that the simple solution is to append the path to the conda file to the LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

> `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path-to-your-conda/envs/your-env-name/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

Comment: I was looking to install a different program but running into the same issue, and no solution worked for me EXCEPT this one. Thanks so much for posting!

Answer (score 14):

### If the accepted answer didn't work, try this

I had the same conditions as the original poster and the accepted answer didn't work as `conda` was taking forever. I tried down-versioning `scipy` from `1.9.3` to `1.9.1` and it did work.

You can use the following command to do so:

```
conda install -c anaconda scipy==1.9.1
```

Answer (score 8):

One solution that fixed this problem for while trying to run mujoco or mujoco-py was as follows

> OSError: /home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/bin/../lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not foundwhen starting ipython. For some reason this library isnt in the
> anaconda environments libstdc++.so.6. It is in the base ubuntu
> library. So link the anaconda version of this library back to the os
> version:

```
cd /home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/lib
mv libstdc++.so.6 libstdc++.so.6.old
ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 libstdc++.so.6
```

credits: https://bcourses.berkeley.edu/courses/1478831/pages/glibcxx-missing

Comment: Yeah, basically used this same approach on another program (not related to "conda"). Sometimes a program gets shipped and packaged with a older version of a library (e.g. "libstdc++"), but a second program that *interfaces* with that first program expects the first program to have a more up-to-date version of the library. Assuming there are no breaking changes in the newer library version, this approach should work just fine--just be *sure* to back up the older library version (e.g. append ".old") just in case.

Comment: I had this problem when using gstreamer (plugin failed to load) and this is what solved it!

Answer (score 2):

So what worked for me was to manually remove Python3.10 which I had installed using `make altinstall` and upgrade scipy to the latest version.

Answer (score 1):

None of the other answers worked for me. This did work though:

```
pip install scikit-build
```

Answer (score 0):

The soln given above doesn't work for me. I got it working by downgrading my scipy from 1.9.1 to 1.6.1.

Answer (score 0):

In some cases, there exist multiple installations of glibcxx and runtime your app wants to connect to it but finds the library in the wrong place. It can be solved by changing the imported libraries' order. The problem has been solved by importing librosa on top of the running script.

Answer (score 0):

None of the other answers worked for me, but this solved the problem:

```
import torch
```

The line is to add in top of file.