# libGL errors during running some python code

Tags: python, anaconda, fedora, numba

there is some problems during some python code with decorator

```
@jit(target_backend ="cuda", forceobj=True)
```

and after that bunch of errors about libGL library missing comes up.
i think this errors could be generated by matplotlib because the project's output is a plot.

```
libGL error: MESA-LOADER: failed to open iris: /home/mohammad/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PIL/../../../././libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.30' not found (required by /usr/lib64/dri/iris_dri.so) (search paths /usr/lib64/dri, suffix _dri)
libGL error: failed to load driver: iris
libGL error: MESA-LOADER: failed to open iris: /home/mohammad/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PIL/../../../././libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.30' not found (required by /usr/lib64/dri/iris_dri.so) (search paths /usr/lib64/dri, suffix _dri)
libGL error: failed to load driver: iris
libGL error: MESA-LOADER: failed to open swrast: /home/mohammad/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PIL/../../../././libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.30' not found (required by /usr/lib64/dri/swrast_dri.so) (search paths /usr/lib64/dri, suffix _dri)
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
```

can you help me please?
im on fedora 36 and using anaconda 22.11.1.

im searching about it but i cant the right way.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73317676/importerror-usr-lib-aarch64-linux-gnu-libstdc-so-6-version-glibcxx-3-4-30
This looks like what you're looking for

Comment: How are packages installed? Are you mixing Conda Forge channel with Anaconda defaults?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ImportError: /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version \`GLIBCXX\_3.4.30' not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73317676/importerror-usr-lib-aarch64-linux-gnu-libstdc-so-6-version-glibcxx-3-4-30)