# version `GLIBCXX_3.4.30' not found

Tags: python, tensorflow, opencv, ubuntu

i'm facing a problem when i'm trying to run an old version python code .
the problem is :
ImportError: /home/gouda/anaconda3/envs/breast/bin/../lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.30' not found (required by /home/gouda/anaconda3/envs/breast/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cv2/cv2.abi3.so)
note that : i'm using ubuntu 22.04LTS with Anaconda
when i searched that error i think it's related to opencv and it's version is 4.7.0

ImportError: /home/gouda/anaconda3/envs/breast/bin/../lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.30' not found (required by /home/gouda/anaconda3/envs/breast/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cv2/cv2.abi3.so)

Comment: any luck resolving this?

Comment: The answer on this other similar question solved it for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72736003/14587004

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned it correctly. `opencv-python 4.7.0.72` supported Python versions are `3.7, 3.8, 3.9, 3.10, 3.11` whereas you have installed Python 3.6 in your system which will be suitable for `opencv-python 4.6.0` as per this [pypi doc](https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/4.6.0.66/).

You can also try by using below code:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libstdc++6
```

and try reinstalling opencv package by specifying the version:

```
pip install opencv-python==4.6.0.66
```

Please have a look at this similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73317676/importerror-usr-lib-aarch64-linux-gnu-libstdc-so-6-version-glibcxx-3-4-30).
Let us know if the issue still persists.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue on Ubuntu 23.04. I am experimenting with the software "eveusb" https://www.net-usb.com/downloads/
The answer is simple in retrospect (for eveusb).

```
cd /opt/ElectronicTeam/eveusb/lib
sudo rm libstdc++.so.6
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 .
```

This corrected the `libstdc++.so.6` issues but, the daemon had the error: `ERROR: could not insert 'eveusb': Key was rejected by service`. This was a MOK issue.

Resolved by paying attention to the installation for the signing path then:

`sudo mokutil --import /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.der`

Reboot and complete importing the key.

Original error below:

```
$ eveusb                                                                                                         
eveusb: /opt/ElectronicTeam/eveusb/bin/../lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.30' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicuuc.so.72)
$ strings /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIBCXX
GLIBCXX_3.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.1
GLIBCXX_3.4.2
GLIBCXX_3.4.3
GLIBCXX_3.4.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.5
GLIBCXX_3.4.6
GLIBCXX_3.4.7
GLIBCXX_3.4.8
GLIBCXX_3.4.9
GLIBCXX_3.4.10
GLIBCXX_3.4.11
GLIBCXX_3.4.12
GLIBCXX_3.4.13
GLIBCXX_3.4.14
GLIBCXX_3.4.15
GLIBCXX_3.4.16
GLIBCXX_3.4.17
GLIBCXX_3.4.18
GLIBCXX_3.4.19
GLIBCXX_3.4.20
GLIBCXX_3.4.21
GLIBCXX_3.4.22
GLIBCXX_3.4.23
GLIBCXX_3.4.24
GLIBCXX_3.4.25
GLIBCXX_3.4.26
GLIBCXX_3.4.27
GLIBCXX_3.4.28
GLIBCXX_3.4.29
GLIBCXX_3.4.30
GLIBCXX_3.4.31
GLIBCXX_3.4.32
GLIBCXX_TUNABLES
GLIBCXX_DEBUG_MESSAGE_LENGTH
```

I had contacted their e-mail support but, no response back.