# How to fix `GLIBCXX_3.4.30' not found in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: .net

Trying to compile dotnet code on ubuntu and get this error:

Failed to load /usr/lib/dotnet/dotnet6-6.0.109/host/fxr/6.0.9/libhostfxr.so, error: /home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.30' not found (required by /usr/lib/dotnet/dotnet6-6.0.109/host/fxr/6.0.9/libhostfxr.so) The library libhostfxr.so was found, but loading it from /usr/lib/dotnet/dotnet6-6.0.109/host/fxr/6.0.9/libhostfxr.so failed

Installing .NET prerequisites might help resolve this problem. https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2063370
dotnet --version and dotnet --info do not work.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/q/72540359/1919793

Answer (score 0):

Update your repositories and install [build-essential](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/build-essential), which contains GCC, *inter alia*:

```bash
sudo apt update
sudo apt install build-essential
```

This package depends on `g++`, which depends on `g++-11`, which depends on `libstdc++-11-dev`, which depends on `libstdc++6`, the package you desire.

You should have thus installed a shared object of the GNU standard C++ library at `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6`. Run the following commands to see the supported versions and which version it points to:

```bash
strings /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIBCXX
ls -la /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
```

Update the symbolic link as needed. Install an older version of the GCC toolchain if necessary. Godspeed.