# ImportError: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.30' not found

Tags: python, linux, machine-learning, nlp, conda

I'm trying to install bern2 locally. bern2 installed successfully. when I started running, I got this error.

ImportError: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.30' not found (required by /opt/conda/envs/bern2/lib/python3.11/site-packages/faiss/../../../libfaiss.so)

```
from normalizers.neural_normalizer import NeuralNormalizer
  File "/home/ubuntu/BERN2/BERN2/normalizers/neural_normalizer.py", line 17, in <module>
    import faiss
  File "/opt/conda/envs/bern2/lib/python3.11/site-packages/faiss/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from .loader import *
  File "/opt/conda/envs/bern2/lib/python3.11/site-packages/faiss/loader.py", line 65, in <module>
    from .swigfaiss import *
  File "/opt/conda/envs/bern2/lib/python3.11/site-packages/faiss/swigfaiss.py", line 10, in <module>
    from . import _swigfaiss
ImportError: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.30' not found (required by /opt/conda/envs/bern2/lib/python3.11/site-packages/faiss/../../../libfaiss.so)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/BERN2/BERN2/server.py", line 1, in <module>
    from app import create_app
  File "/home/ubuntu/BERN2/BERN2/app/__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    import bern2
  File "/home/ubuntu/BERN2/BERN2/bern2/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from bern2.bern2 import BERN2
  File "/home/ubuntu/BERN2/BERN2/bern2/bern2.py", line 22, in <module>
    from normalizer import Normalizer
  File "/home/ubuntu/BERN2/BERN2/bern2/normalizer.py", line 11, in <module>
    from normalizers.neural_normalizer import NeuralNormalizer
  File "/home/ubuntu/BERN2/BERN2/normalizers/neural_normalizer.py", line 17, in <module>
    import faiss
  File "/opt/conda/envs/bern2/lib/python3.11/site-packages/faiss/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from .loader import *
  File "/opt/conda/envs/bern2/lib/python3.11/site-packages/faiss/loader.py", line 65, in <module>
    from .swigfaiss import *
  File "/opt/conda/envs/bern2/lib/python3.11/site-packages/faiss/swigfaiss.py", line 10, in <module>
    from . import _swigfaiss
ImportError: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.30' not found (required by /opt/conda/envs/bern2/lib/python3.11/site-packages/faiss/../../../libfaiss.so)
```

Comment: Looks like you need to update libstdc++. The answers in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72540359/glibcxx-3-4-30-not-found-for-librosa-in-conda-virtual-environment-after-tryin) question might help.

Comment: I've tried. all nothing worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

The reason could be that the system path is not configured correctly. Try this,

`export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$CONDA_PREFIX/lib/`

Source:
https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip

Answer (score 1):

it works for me that update libstdc++

```bash
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

check the result

```bash
strings /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIBCXX
```