# usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.29' not found

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, scipy, anaconda

Well, there are plenty solutions for me online, but none have worked for me yet.

I just can use conda or pip.

I am getting this error:

```
    from scipy.stats import norm
  File "/home/user/.conda/envs/def/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy/stats/__init__.py", line 467, in <module>
    from ._stats_py import *
  File "/home/user/.conda/envs/def/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy/stats/_stats_py.py", line 39, in <module>
    from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist
  File "/home/user/.conda/envs/def/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy/spatial/__init__.py", line 105, in <module>
    from ._kdtree import *
  File "/home/user/.conda/envs/def/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy/spatial/_kdtree.py", line 5, in <module>
    from ._ckdtree import cKDTree, cKDTreeNode
ImportError: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.29' not found (required by /home/user/.conda/envs/def/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy/spatial/_ckdtree.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
```

I have installed:

```
torch                         2.0.0.post200
torchvision                   0.15.2a0+072ec57
scipy                         1.10.1
```

---

Edit:

This error pops up when I use `import torchattacks`.

Comment: Not enough info. Where *exactly* is everything installed from and what does `conda info` output? Does this issue arise with a fresh environment? (e.g., `conda create -n so-test python=3.8 scipy`, then try `python -c 'from scipy.stats import norm'`). If this is a Conda Forge package, please file an issue on [the Conda Forge `scipy` feedstock](https://github.com/conda-forge/scipy-feedstock/issues).

Comment: @merv no, it does not depend only on scipy. There many different packages installed and at some point it does not work out anymore.

Comment: Yes, but the stacktrace implicates `from scipy.stats import norm`. Without a minimal example of how to recreate it, there isn't much precise advice to be given. Could you please add output from `conda list --export -n def`? Python versions are insufficient information to identify where the package is sourced from.

Comment: @merv the minimal example is:  `import torchattacks`.

Comment: Not enough info to replicate. Please provide steps to create an environment that fails with this code.

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting error. I got this multiple times; different solutions worked at different times. Here are some of the ways that worked for me:

##### Install GCC and G++ in your conda environment

```py
conda install -c conda-forge gcc=12.3.0
```

```py
conda install -c conda-forge gxx=12.3.0
```

This is the easiest of all, but I found this approach to be not very reliable, at least in my case. I explored some more ways to resolve the issue, as mentioned below.

##### Manual path addition

Here's the related answer for more details: ['GLIBCXX_3.4.30' not found for librosa in conda virtual environment (after trying out a lot of solutions)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72540359/14473589)

```py
strings /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIBCXX_3.4.30
```

```py
strings /path-to-your-conda-env/lib/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIBCXX_3.4.30
```

```py
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path-to-your-conda-env/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

This solution, too, didn't consistently resolve the issue. I explored another method mentioned below.

##### Manual copy and paste of `libstdc++.so.6`

```py
whereis libstdc++.so.6
cp /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 /path-to-your-conda-env/lib/
whereis libstdc++.so.6
which libstdc++.so.6
ls /path-to-your-conda-env/lib/libstdc++.so.6
```

This proved to be a reliable solution for me—consistently working until now!

I hope this answer helps you! Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, but doing stuff like this is what leads to these problems in the first place. One should never need to manipulate library loading with Conda. If you hit library loading problems with Conda it's either something needs to be fixed in a Conda recipe (pls create an issue on the corresponding feedstock) or you're doing something bad like mixing packages across channels, in which case we need more information than just an error message.

Comment: Thanks for your informative comment, @merv! I'll keep this in my mind. You are right; just importing a package should not cause such errors. In my case, I built PyTorch from the source. Therefore, I needed that. I will check further to see if there's any way not to do this. Thanks!

Comment: @khushi  well I am getting the error then wrong glibcxx version then, when I copied and based manually.