# ValueError when calling inspect.signature on hashlib.md5

Tags: python, gcc, conda, hashlib

I am encountering an exception when attempting to retrieve the signature of the hashlib.md5
function:

```
inspect.signature(hashlib.md5)

ValueError: 'usedforsecurity=?' is not a valid parameter name
```

on Python 3.10.8. What could be the reason and how can I avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

This could be traced back to the installation of the conda gcc package. The underlying reason remains unknown.  Full reproducible example:

```
# 1. set up new environment
conda create -n pythontest python==3.10
conda activate pythontest

# 2. test python command in fresh environment
python -c "import hashlib, inspect; print(inspect.signature(hashlib.md5))"

# output as expected: (string=b'', *, usedforsecurity=True)

# 3. install gcc
conda install -c conda-forge gcc=12.1.0

# 4. rerun python command
python -c "import hashlib, inspect; print(inspect.signature(hashlib.md5))"

# ValueError: 'usedforsecurity=?' is not a valid parameter name
```

In my particular case, gcc was installed due to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72736003/10020283) answer solving the common `'GLIBCXX_3.4.30' not found` error.

I am now avoiding installing gcc by using [this](https://github.com/isl-org/Open3D/issues/5531#issuecomment-1250141991) alternative approach.

Comment: The only part here that addresses the question is the link at the end. The rest (the MRE) should be in the question and the actual answer expanded here.

Comment: @Woodford No, you are assuming that the we already know that gcc is the underlying cause of this error, but it is only the answer that identifies it as such.

Comment: *How can I avoid this?* The only thing addressing this question is an external link.

Comment: Point taken, I rephrased the question.